# How to make a google sheets script that returns notes on cells from another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently working on a spreadsheet and need a modification on the standard getNote script.  Basically, on the mainpage I have a dropdown menu that collects names from another page and returns their corresponding information from another sheet via vLookup.

I'm trying to implement a system where selecting a name from the dropdown menu will return any notes written on the cell containing the name on the other sheet.

I have a very basic understanding of google apps scripts, but can't seem to create a script that works.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Right now I only have the basic getNote script:

```
function getNote(cell) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getComment();
}
```

I'm trying to make the script get any given name in Cell b3 in sheet1, find the corresponding cell containing the name in sheet2, and return the note contained on the cell in sheet 2 to sheet 1.

Comment: Hello welcome to SO, show us what you have written so far.

Comment: Thanks! @JamesWong, I've added what I have so far to the main post.

Comment: Why don't you try with some basic Google Apps Script tutorials to read/write data into a Google Sheet. This will help you in retrieving your selected name, searching for it Sheet2 and returning the linked note. Tutorial links [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-intro/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0), [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials) and [here](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/starting-gas/).